# Moving Hamburger Menu - React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to move my hamburger menu to the right. Nothing has worked, and it continues to stay on the left. I have tried float, shift right, alignment, and many other things. I have read all of the articles on Stack Overflow regarding this, but nothing has solved my issue. Would someone be able to assist me?

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';


// in the function the return will show what the html will look like
function NavigationBar( {user} ) {
return (
        <>
        <Navbar bg="navBackground" variant="dark" expand="lg">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav'/>
                <Nav className='m-auto'>
                    <Nav.Link href="#about">About</Nav.Link>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                        {
                        {linksToUse.map((link) => (
                            <Nav.Link>{link}</Nav.Link>
                        ))}
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Nav>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}

// export the component so it can be used outside of this file
export default NavigationBar;
```

```
/*Background color of the nav bar*/
.bg-navBackground{
    background-color: #333;
}

/*Makes the navbar icon background #333*/
.navbar-toggler-icon{
    background-color: #333;
} 

/*Makes the background of the collapse area #333*/
.navbar-collapse{
    background-color: #333;
}

/*Text color of nav links*/
.nav-link{
    color: #638797 !important;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center; /*Makes text centered in nav when screen sizes are smaller*/
}

/*Makes text appear white upon hovering*/
.nav-link:hover{
    color: white !important;
}

/*Makes the rest of the nav bar #333*/
.container{
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: We can definitely help you, but it will be a lot easier if you post a link to a CodeSandbox or other place where we can see your code in action - getting all of your packages installed and working will probably be a bit more work than most StackOverflow answerers (myself included) really want to put in.

Comment: Did you want to have the About link always showing?  Or should it be collapsed with the rest of the links?

Comment: @jme11 I want the About to be showing! It looked weird just having the hamburger icon haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason you're experiencing this is that the container component when wrapping a navbar applies flex and justify-content: space-between.  Ostensibly this is because in most applications you'd have a "brand" component on the starting side and the menu toggle on the left.  The simple answer is that you can remove the container, or change the `justify-content` property.

You also have a little bit of a wrinkle with the way you're wrapping your links with the Navbar.Collapse component on the inside of the Nav component.  I think I get that you're doing this so that you can have the About displayed in the center of the navbar without collapsing, while also allowing it be inline with the rest of the links when the navigation isn't collapsed.  The issue is that you don't get the nice transition when opening and collapsing the menu.

I did a couple of different demos for you to give you both the transition and to keep the About link in the center as well.

Also, I modified your CSS a bit to remove some of the backgrounds that were covering up the toggle (they were unneeded anyway).

See if any of these work for you: [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-navbar-demo-66fuod).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me! This helped so so much.